# Сортировка вставками не работает для вектора

Tags: c++

```
void DirectInclusion(vector<int> a, int n)  {  
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    int j, x, assigns = 0, cmp = 0, L = 0, R = n - 1, pos = 0; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)  {  
 
        L = i; 
        pos = -1; 
        x = a[i]; 
        j = i-1 ; 
         
        while (x < a[j] && j >= 0)  {  
            a[j + 1] = a[j]; 
            j = j - 1; 
            assigns++; 
             
         }  
        a[j + 1] = x; 
        pos = j + 1; 
        assigns++; 
        if (pos == -1)  {  
            ++cmp; 
            break; 
         }  
        R = pos; 
        i = R; 
      
         
     }  
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    std::chrono::duration<double> seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1); 
    printf("|%-24s|%18d|%24d|%22d|%28.10f|\n", "Метод простого включения", n, cmp, assigns, seconds.count()); 
 } 

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); 
 
    vector<int> masS1(20); 
    masS1 =  {  25,2,100,4,10,22,25,25,27,102,75,200,12,1,55,32,69,80,15,2  } ; 
    
    cout << "1 задание: " << endl << endl; 
    printf("|%-24s|%-18s|%-24s|%-22s|%-28s|\n", "------------------------", "------------------", "------------------------", "----------------------", "----------------------------"); 
    printf("|%-24s|%-18s|%-24s|%-22s|%-28s|\n", "Метод", "Размер массива", "Количество сравнений", "Количество обменов", "Скорость"); 
    printf("|%-24s|%-18s|%-24s|%-22s|%-28s|\n", "------------------------", "------------------", "------------------------", "----------------------", "----------------------------"); 
    
    DirectInclusion(masS1, 20); 
   
    cout << endl; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  {  
        cout << masS1[i] << " "; 
     }
```

Сделал сортировку методом прямого включения.Вылазит ошибка vector subscript is out of range.Для обычного массива все нормально работает. Не вижу, где вылезает за пределы вектора. Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
a[j + 1] = x;
```

Проверь значение j + 1 - оно должно быть меньше размера вектора. У тебя оно доходит до 20.